# CSS Keyword for div wrapping (similar to overflow: hidden)

Tags: css

I know I used this specific CSS keyword a while ago, but I can't recall it's name.

It has a similar behavior to `overflow: hidden`, where it causes the element to wrap around margins and floating containers. It's not `flex` or `clear` shenanigans.

I tried to look for it, but there is too much overlap with `overflow: hidden` results to find anything about it - does anyone know what that CSS keyword was? Something with "root" in the word, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find it. It's called `display: flow-root`.

> "It always establishes a new block formatting context for its
> contents."

https://css-tricks.com/display-flow-root/

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display-3/#valdef-display-flow-root